# Bluebird promisify not wrapping node style function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm stumped on why Bluebird's Promise.promisify isn't promisifying my query function because it takes a callback like most node style functions.  Could it be Mongoose's aggregation() method that's breaking the code?

```
function query(callback) {
  model.aggregate([{$sort:{a: -1}}], function(err, items) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    let mostA = items[0].a;
    Caller.aggregate([{$sort:{b: -1}}], function(err, items) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      let mostB = items[0].b;
      callback({mostA: mostA, mostB: mostB});
    });
  });
};

let most = Promise.promisify(query);

most()
.then((data) => {
  // do something
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('err:', err); // I always get an error.
});
```

Comment: That's not a node style callback???

Comment: If you are writing this function yourself, you rather should promisify those `aggregate` methods.

Comment: Yes, `model.aggregate()` is what needs to be promisified, not `query()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a node style callback.  A node style callback must do the following:

1. The callback must be the last argument to the method (you're good on that one).
2. The callback must have two arguments (you're not good on this)
3. The first argument to the callback must be an error value that is truthy whenever there is an error (you're not good on this).
4. The second argument to the callback must be whatever data is being returned (if any).

In addition, your `query()` function does not do proper error handling.  It needs to call the callback with the error value as the first argument and then stop further processing.

So, when you do this:

```
callback({mostA: mostA, mostB: mostB});
```

You are telling the callback that there is an error because you are passing the first argument as a truthy value.

If you want to make it the right form, you would do this:

```
 callback(null, {mostA: mostA, mostB: mostB});
```

Comment: @MichaelL - Did this answer your question? If so, please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and to earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.  If not, please explain what part of your question you are still confused about.